# German Umlauts in strftime date-formatting - correct utf-8 encoding?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, diacritics

I'm creating a german date format like this with PHP `14. März 2012` (which is March 14th 2012).

I'm working with `$date[0]` that contains a unix timestamp and I convert it like this to a readable german date.

```
$date_day_month = strftime('%d. %B', $date[0]);
$date_year = strftime('%Y', $date[0]);

echo $date_day_month . $date_year;
```

However I somehow get a question mark for the Umlaut `ä` like this

`14. M�rz 2012`

Why is that and how can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is uft-8 encoding (in the title of the question) a typo?  I guess you mean UTF-8?

Comment: @user1180316 Was a typo. Sorry. @Dagon I have `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` in my `head`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to make your webpage utf-8, put this in your `head` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

`strftime` is depending on the right setting of the locale, so check your `setlocale()` and make sure that locale exists on the machine that php has running.

**Update**

I ran this code on my server:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');
$date[0] = mktime( 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2012 );

$date_day_month = strftime('%d. %B', $date[0]);
$date_year = strftime('%Y', $date[0]);

echo $date_day_month . $date_year;
```

And that outputs:

`02. März2012`

Comment: Hmm, doesn't make a difference and I do already have `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` in my `head`. The rest of the page (based on Wordpress) works fine with all Umlauts, just this date makes problems.

Comment: Well, thank you, but that's not it either … I tested this `$locale = get_locale();
//setlocale(LC_TIME, $locale);
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');` So I already had the locale set correctly since my entire blog is in german it has the right locale settings. I tried adding the `setlocale` line exactly like you suggest even a second time but no success.

Comment: hmm .. out of options then. As you see I used exact the same code, and I get correct output. Perhaps a link to your blog?

Comment: This might be some problem with the Hosting Provider as I just tested it locally on my local-server where everything seems to work fine. Could that be the reason? I wonder why the rest is working then?

Comment: I just copied and pasted, and at my webserver it is also working. As I said, the locale must exist on the webserver. Perhaps it is not de_DE but de_DE.utf8 ??

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much! I added `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8');` and now it works just fine!

Answer (score 49):

In my case a simple change of the locale did the trick.

Instead of:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");
```

Use:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE.UTF-8");
```

Comment: the suggested "de_DE-UTF-8" or in my case "de_AT.UTF-8", respectively "de_AT.utf8" as seen in the php manual is not available on my hosting (Windows Azure Websites (=PaaS)), I have to use "german_austria" but this is not an UTF8 locale and thus outputs ä's ö's and ü's as � - have you got an Idea how to fix that or how to find out all installed locales with php - its a windows machine running IIS8 but as its just a hosted website, I have no system access.

Comment: @DanielSteiner As a workaround, wrap your `strftime` call in `utf8_encode`. See https://php.net/manual/en/resourcebundle.locales.php for how to get a list of all supported locales.

Comment: Works like a charm for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows environment (XAMPP), `setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE.UTF-8")` did not solve the problem for me, so I resorted to using locale `"de"` and then - as @Chris suggested in his comment to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18229644/1460043) - converted the string manually to utf8:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de");
$maerzLatin1 = strftime('%B', mktime(9, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2016));
$maerzUtf8 = utf8_encode($maerzLatin1);  // this one contains "März" UTF8-encoded
```