# Character encoding within German date created with strftime()

Tags: php, wordpress, strftime

This is about wrong display of spelled-out German month names which contain special characters (Umlaut, basically only the letter "ä" in "März" - German for March). I am trying to display it like "28. März 2012".

This is in Wordpress, BTW. In the header I have the `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag. The corresponding template file contains the following line to get the month names in German:

```
setlocale (LC_ALL, 'de_AT@euro', 'de_AT', 'de', 'ge');
```

Actually, this code is for "Austrian German", but it shouldn't make a difference for the month of March = März.

For the page I am fetching a string from the database which represents a date, for example "18.03.2012". Then I convert that string to a "real" PHP `date()`:

```
$date_start = date_create($date_string_from_database);
```

Since I need to compare that date to another timestamp, I convert it to a `timestamp` like this (adding a fixed time of 20:00):

```
$timestamp_start = strtotime(date_format($date_start, 'Y-m-j 20:00'));
```

And sometime later I create a formated date with spelled-out German month names from this timestamp like this:

```
$date_german = strftime("%e. %B %Y", $timestamp_start);
```

Now, in my localhost installation, this is displayed as expected:

[image]

But on the performance server, I get this:

[image]

**All other special characters (including "ä") on that page are displayed correctly**, it must have to do with the way the server handles that `strftime` function or the `setlocale` settings. FWIW, also the generated HTML code contains that "?" character instead of "ä". The PHP version is 5.6 in both cases.

Any idea what I could do to get it displayed correctly?

EDIT / ADDITION concerning possible duplicate: This has nothing to do with the charset meta tag (which I set, as I described in my question), and also not with encoding/decoding database results. The methos in the accepted answer works well for me, and that solution is not mentioned in the would-be-duplicate.

Comment: Or, if that's too general: [German Umlauts in strftime date-formatting - correct utf-8 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680716/german-umlauts-in-strftime-date-formatting-correct-utf-8-encoding)

Comment: @miken32 Okay, the latter one might apply, but the answer there is different from the answer below which works well for me.

Comment: Check the answer at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use utf8_encode.

```
$date_german = strftime("%e. %B %Y", $timestamp_start);
$date_german = utf8_encode($date_german);
```

Comment: @johannes Also check the list of available locales on the server system. There may be a specific locale that already supports utf-8. See for example this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18229644/101087

Comment: This is a *bad* solution. It only works if the locale happens to use ISO-8859-1 encoding, and breaks the same way in all other circumstances.

Comment: Today the PHP version changed, and unfortunately that method doesn't work anymore now. I got it to work by including `setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_AT.UTF-8");`  and then `$date_german = strftime("%e. %B %Y", $timestamp_start);`