# typo3 viewhelper date delivers empty string for every date in march

Tags: typo3

TYPO3 v11, PHP 8.0.8.

The following line in a fluid template:

```
<f:format.date format="%d. %B %y">{newsItem.datetime}</f:format.date>
```

delivers an empty string for every date in march.

I got the following debug outputs for a date in february:

```
DateTimeprototypeobject (2023-02-06T13:15:46+01:00, 1675685746)
' 06. Februar 23 ' (28 chars)
```

So the locale is correct and i get local dates in german.

But for dates in march i get the following debug output:

```
DateTimeprototypeobject (2023-03-07T16:00:08+01:00, 1678201208)
'' (25 chars)
```

The Datetime-Object is correct but the formatted string is empty.

Any ideas whats going on here?
Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be a locale issue. As the German "March" has an umlaut, the system can't output due to locale or even utf-8 settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two possible solutions are already registered at SO:
[German Umlauts in strftime date-formatting - correct utf-8 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680716/german-umlauts-in-strftime-date-formatting-correct-utf-8-encoding)
[Character encoding within German date created with strftime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54335144/character-encoding-within-german-date-created-with-strftime)

1. make sure your locale is set with UTF8 encoding:
   `setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE.UTF-8");`
   (make sure the the name is written correct and compare it with the list of available locals with this shell command: `locale -a | grep -i "de_de"`)

regarding TYPO3: set `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['systemLocale']`

2. encode the result for further usage:

```
$date_german = strftime("%e. %B %Y", $timestamp_start);
$date_german = utf8_encode($date_german);
```

maybe with an additional ViewHelper???

Comment: the problem was indeed a wrong locale - which i not realized because it was only a typo: de_DE.utf-8 instead of de_DE.utf8 ... both exists and only one is correct.

Comment: the name of the current locale can vary from system to system. I added a hint to get the currently active locals on a system.